# Converting XML to CSV, each entry on new line

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I'm converting XML into CSV using a XSLT, but when applying the XSL to the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report>
<Dates>
  <Current>02/02/2014</Current>
  <Previous>02/02/2013</Previous>
</Dates>
<Entry>
  <Category>1</Category>
  <Data1>10.00</Data1>
  <Data2>20.00</Data2>
</Entry>
<Entry>
  <Category>2</Category>
  <Data1>30.00</Data1>
  <Data2>40.00</Data2>
</Entry>
<Entry>
  <Category>3</Category>
  <Data1>50.00</Data1>
  <Data2>60.00</Data2>
</Entry>
<Entry>
  <Category>4</Category>
  <Data1>70.00</Data1>
  <Data2>80.00</Data2>
</Entry>
<Totals>
  <TCurrent>160.00</TCurrent>
  <TPrevious>200.00</TPrevious>
</Totals>
</Report>
```

XSL file I am using is following:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="Report/Dates/child::*">   
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:value-of select="."/>,</xsl:if>    
    <xsl:if test="position()  = last()"><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>                         

    Number, Data1 , Data2   
    <xsl:for-each select="Report/Entry/child::*">   
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:value-of select="."/>,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position()  = last()"><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text></xsl:if>   
    </xsl:for-each>                         

    <xsl:for-each select="Report/Totals/child::*">
    <xsl:if test="position()  = 1">Totals,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:value-of select="."/>,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position()  = last()"><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>                                     
</xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting one long line with all entries, like

```
02/02/2014, 02/02/2013
1, 10.00, 20.00, 2, 30.00, 40.00, 3, 50.00, 60.00, 4, 70.00, 80.00
Totals, 160.00, 200.00
```

Question: what to do to get an every entry on new line, I need the result like

```
02/02/2014, 02/02/2013 
1, 10.00, 20.00 
2, 30.00, 40.00 
3, 50.00, 60.00 
4, 70.00, 80.00 
Totals, 160.00, 200.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:for-each select="Report/Entry/child::*">
```

So for all the children of *all* the Entry items

You want one carriage return per entry so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Report/Entry">   
  <xsl:for-each select="*">   
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:value-of select="."/>,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position()  = last()"><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text></xsl:if>   
  </xsl:for-each>      
</xsl:for-each>
```

So that you are 'breaking up' the set into entries and then placing the CR after each

NB child:: is the default axis, ie `Report/Totals/child::*` <=> `Report/Totals/*`

Comment: Thank you. I thought that `Report/Entry/child::*` is the same as `<xsl:for-each select="Report/Entry">   
  <xsl:for-each select="*">`

Comment: @SU_ And you were right, in principle. In my opinion, this answer is not very helpful, because it does not explain the problem, nor the solution. See my answer for the details.

Answer (score 0):

As with all programming languages, there are styles of programming that work, but are considered bad or uncanonical ways of solving the problem. That's the case with only matching `/` and heavy use of `for-each` loops in the code.

Therefore, I would argue that the accepted answer to your question merely scratches the surface of the problem without really bringing about improvement. I'd suggest a much simpler approach, in case you can use XSLT 2.0.

**XSLT Stylesheet (2.0)**

Match all child elements of `Report` in the same template, using `|`. Then, `string-join()` all of their child elements, separating the content with `,`. Use an XPath 2.0 conditional expression to decide whether or not to output a carriage return.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"  encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="Dates|Entry|Totals">
        <xsl:if test="self::Totals">
            <xsl:text>Totals, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="string-join(*,', ')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="if (position() != last()) then '&#xD;' else ''"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Text Output**

As you can see, the output is exactly what you requested.

```
02/02/2014, 02/02/2013
1, 10.00, 20.00
2, 30.00, 40.00
3, 50.00, 60.00
4, 70.00, 80.00
Totals, 160.00, 200.00
```

---

Also, perhaps more importantly, **why does your original code not work?** This is what it looks like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Report/Entry/child::*">   
  <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:value-of select="."/>,</xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="position()  = last()"><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text></xsl:if>   
</xsl:for-each>
```

The problem is that `for-each` loops over a sequence of nodes, in this case all children of `Entry` elements. In this new sequence, there is only **one** last element, not several, as you had expected. So, this `if`:

```
<xsl:if test="position()  = last()"><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
```

is only triggered once, for the very last child of the last `Entry` element. That's why all the content is on the same line, and there is only one `&#xD;` at the end of the line.

> I thought that `Report/Entry/child::*` is the same as `<xsl:for-each select="Report/Entry"> <xsl:for-each select="*">`

Yes, they target the same nodes, but the behaviour of `position()` is different.